# CSS Bootstrap 4 class with 'input-group-append' isn't correctly working. Last week the display of Styles are right

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, button, bootstrap-4

My web app with AngularJS 1.7.8, jQuery 3.3.1, Bootstrap 4.3.1 and some others CSS- and JS-libraries/frameworks worked without any problems last week.

But today, I see a wrong visualization of appending buttons.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Go to openskymap.org to see my demo app.
2. Open (click) the menu item "Calendar" to proceed out to the Calendar Page.
3. Here check the proper visualization of the Button with the ID 'dateRangePicker1GlyphButton1'.

See:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYyl2.png)

**Issue:** 
The button isn't appended on the input field of daterangepicker. But last week the button was appended correctly. Also the glyphiconis is now white (last week black).

**Desired behavior like this:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n61wo.png)

- appended Button
- black glyph icon

**The code snippet:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- define angular app -->
<html lang="de" xml:lang="de" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" ng-app="sensorsApp">
<head>
     <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8" /> <!-- HTML5 HTTP-Header --> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> <!-- HTML4 HTTP-Header -->
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/css; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/javascript; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  
  <!-- USED CSS: GENERAL (1/2) -->
  <!--  > GENERAL: CUSTOM PROJECT STYLES -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/project.css">    
    
  <!-- USED CSS: BOOTSTRAP -->
  <!--  > BOOTSTRAP FONT LIBS: -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha256-nAmazAk6vS34Xqo0BSrTb+abbtFlgsFK7NKSi6o7Y78= sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr sha512-3M00D/rn8n+2ZVXBO9Hib0GKNpkm8MSUU/e2VNthDyBYxKWG+BftNYYcuEjXlyrSO637tidzMBXfE7sQm0INUg==" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!--  > BOOTSTRAP 4: -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha256-YLGeXaapI0/5IgZopewRJcFXomhRMlYYjugPLSyNjTY= sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T sha512-tDXPcamuZsWWd6OsKFyH6nAqh/MjZ/5Yk88T5o+aMfygqNFPan1pLyPFAndRzmOWHKT+jSDzWpJv8krj6x1LMA==" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
  <!-- USED CSS: GENERAL (2/2) -->
  <!--  > GENERAL: BOOTSTRAP DATE(TIME)PICKER -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" integrity="sha256-5Z/4A9O2iG86Ca27OwgMwLmRYt9bjLOoEpPXy7yhiSs= sha384-8wYGNo4TwC9xzqNRdt7OUN789eBPzNQlO/sxIKaJR1gkX0+Ok1kXxhHR4pZU+gP2 sha512-Dapa+NBx6nVgt1Q5L+vn8oXI+bcHD9qpWmWNlkqAIlzz6cpwb6IsEthpkmV455sUDs2FXAZKyNz4hY1Dl0xGyg==" crossorigin="anonymous">  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" integrity="sha256-7B9s/BwXySAt0TMN6/mo6NCBm8oCfFNqaeJlz/9FCpE= sha384-3J4adb6KqO9u+ZgVfdmUqKDG4qWyG2qxGdXYoCXh3YmBQURWveIDgFh22pw1E3a9 sha512-gjpWBCm7COvj1rB4CrNkBAV+Uoxivp/2LPKpZkKcnFS4dDGhQtxdNgn4b8hLltoEVHu7LktbSf8dH8Igm/vi6A==" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/datepickk@1.4.1/dist/datepickk.min.css" integrity="sha256-8pYhYq1SmTPr+/nu2genJ7ko5oPwyiY3TJN0UAAZGQw= sha384-M2Romq884NkvgBkdz3NdXBwgPBO8cCs0keFrHmCWoNQ+tJYBpktQErbvcD7gKXae sha512-zFB5O2YjVX9hdpLmz13ClhpHkX1MWNjuyfFlIiGUR9ziBrSvcpp4hx+qfpBZFsVHPHfMg1HFbC8E5uDf9Fd6HA==" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!--  > GENERAL: BOOTSTRAP CHARTS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0/dist/Chart.min.css" integrity="sha256-aa0xaJgmK/X74WM224KMQeNQC2xYKwlAt08oZqjeF0E= sha384-q9MZ/PQCC1nIFQdrr9yNOFXeSaXjv/yPOJOdBd32aODh8+EM6udfo91a6mRbEDih sha512-/zs32ZEJh+/EO2N1b0PEdoA10JkdC3zJ8L5FTiQu82LR9S/rOQNfQN7U59U9BC12swNeRAz3HSzIL2vpp4fv3w==" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.7.5/css/mdb.min.css" integrity="sha256-VSBoWx3wZz4Z6YAMGq1toMWvJN3G1w7KH+b61PGwppA= sha384-WxBbLYERKrFMTQ9LAaSYPo5qW9PJSzV6pbbaX8PqD20S4yudCgwblvRmuhXU6iWD sha512-vltzTDeCDN3MBaISvgsAAv6vJfbJkhjTokn/UttmEVCo0UEOsm7yhgqWJ3n0d5Wz/Fl8ZZSdLyyn7YGGbGwNYg==" crossorigin="anonymous">  
  
  <!-- USED SCRIPTS: GENERAL (1/2) -->
  <!--  > GENERAL: Needed polyfills for working Luxon with supporting IE 10 or 11 -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.js?features=default,es5,es6,es7,String.prototype.repeat,Array.prototype.find,Array.prototype.findIndex,Math.trunc,Math.sign&flags=gated" crossorigin="anonymous" charset="UTF-8"></script>
  <!--  > GENERAL: jQuery 3 -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8= sha384-tsQFqpEReu7ZLhBV2VZlAu7zcOV+rXbYlF2cqB8txI/8aZajjp4Bqd+V6D5IgvKT sha512-+NqPlbbtM1QqiK8ZAo4Yrj2c4lNQoGv8P79DPtKzj++l5jnN39rHA/xsqn8zE9l0uSoxaCdrOgFs6yjyfbBxSg==" crossorigin="anonymous" charset="UTF-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js" integrity="sha256-jDnOKIOq2KNsQZTcBTEnsp76FnfMEttF6AV2DF2fFNE= sha384-hKAOvu4SRkR5UhOl+rvozhqPNh0VgjTz0sydNTzye3vkV6VzpbLACSgthC2bhXeV sha512-CEiA+78TpP9KAIPzqBvxUv8hy41jyI3f2uHi7DGp/Y/Ka973qgSdybNegWFciqh6GrN2UePx2KkflnQUbUhNIA==" crossorigin="anonymous" charset="UTF-8"></script>
 </head>
 <!-- define angular controller -->
 <body ng-controller="mainController">
    
  <div class="container justify-content-md-center justify-content-center">
   <form id="dateTimeRangeSelectionForm1" class="form-group" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-sm">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="row">
        <label class="form-control-label">Selected date/time range:</label>
       </div>
       <div class="input-group date row">
        <input type="daterange" id="dateRangePicker1" name="dateRangePicker1" class="form-control" ng-model="dateRangePicker1"></input>
        <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#dateRangePicker1">
         <button type="button" id="dateRangePicker1GlyphButton1" class="input-group-text form-control btn" role="button"><i class="fas fa-calendar"></i></button>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>

 <!-- USED SCRIPTS: BOOTSTRAP -->
 <!--  > BOOTSTRAP GENERAL: --> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZvOgfh+ptkpoa2Y4HkRY28ir89u/+VRyDE7sB7hEEcI= sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1 sha512-5WvZa4N7Jq3TVNCp4rjcBMlc6pT3lZ7gVxjtI6IkKW+uItSa+rFgtFljvZnCxQGj8SUX5DHraKE6Mn/4smK1Cg==" crossorigin="anonymous" charset="UTF-8"></script>
 <!--  > BOOTSTRAP 4: -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha256-CjSoeELFOcH0/uxWu6mC/Vlrc1AARqbm/jiiImDGV3s= sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM sha512-Ah5hWYPzDsVHf9i2EejFBFrG2ZAPmpu4ZJtW4MfSgpZacn+M9QHDt+Hd/wL1tEkk1UgbzqepJr6KnhZjFKB+0A==" crossorigin="anonymous" charset="UTF-8"></script> 
  
 <!-- USED SCRIPTS: ANGULARJS1 -->
 <!-- AngularJS 1: -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js" integrity="sha256-23hi0Ag650tclABdGCdMNSjxvikytyQ44vYGo9HyOrU= sha384-TBbVc3SDLcWU5RloNEsoiDVvRK9iYkBNMm1OsAcOIVEASb7zzMWB0aMobj6CzKUw sha512-28WMav3WUIziq1D5l+8y2BrzN+CJgEeIyLksiKOSHWofTgaZc3RMPzvleRhXbLwnzf/C7Xnb0W6pE8PlqeRSog==" crossorigin="anonymous" charset="UTF-8"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular-route.js" integrity="sha256-AL1+LnGW9wl5bbvR2aXuGAmYsPKLYHzFbeRyHvPUHw8= sha384-I+qxwVtb8G6V2DkR4JZQBtMe7WBcZkOhEoYoYcvePXVXyQGJDRmZ5vYNRoavfaJ6 sha512-lkwD93i2YxHwDdR41e/MhAl2nm68FsG3x6MdIkmcDaNu8gTgvwyxMxHEiP11fyD9+lpgnUSnPC//NwhAYPS58g==" crossorigin="anonymous" charset="UTF-8"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular-sanitize.js" integrity="sha256-fe1CNxJdqcp2+X9H3Sd0yqtxOv0cyK9DN52g+NhnBgQ= sha384-I3+wmR2cuftFax1/khkYCw2l/24RBOm7dRvcOCGUesC9HveXuL9Gt2QI82rmENt6 sha512-Qxi9FQdJbTxZaVDSVzShM6J67oXjN6MEZ8nn5Fl83fdd9dxsZqX6yDJspSjeKK6Q12FOx6DIQd8l/fe9h1r0ng==" crossorigin="anonymous" charset="UTF-8"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-translate/2.18.1/angular-translate.min.js" integrity="sha256-aOs2ICGLk6gC0UX7UDhvXn/gvsa2qx5bUipyQFKmoOs= sha384-A+zN6Osqnkp8ThR1gJEJ4/dVw2Zwfz0llOo7BnyciCz1isb6OENEo8xfHx1gTWLX sha512-U5WInQAQvpR1C+dLWjcpVygbeof6FylSTlLbUC6eQml4iiEKcNhtPi0GSLCNRIcycohEV5IjfU/HPNHx+lI+Dw==" crossorigin="anonymous" charset="UTF-8"></script>  
  
 <!-- USED SCRIPTS: GENERAL (2/2) -->
 <!--  > GENERAL: ANGULARJS CONTROLLER -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/controller.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
 <!--  > GENERAL: MOMENT.JS -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js" integrity="sha256-AdQN98MVZs44Eq2yTwtoKufhnU+uZ7v2kXnD5vqzZVo= sha384-5wvDEKtdpg/AAUpUHtcjYKVs1qv2V/UFPCN2FNvgePyaKmpBjW+LrboDEuS5ssBe sha512-hlLgIh4nncb2yc4YPtWk5wOykcFxF0fBd5rHfJ6xsALI2khY3H8LbivswJE5Fpz7hws7CJCqOzdyjWHiKJYl+A==" crossorigin="anonymous" charset="UTF-8"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js" integrity="sha256-15jnh2lee6Li94j6XCbw8PRzNZe29O/W9i97yXVyRmA= sha384-bnidgWGLxxEZXPx1eX9mXLAvpkXkRL3iQbkgEksVnj5tlsiymxadIxiM7q5a88Ji sha512-27vEz6bCFnYQ6tNjguaA5DK5TOGme/fdDxbEtuZxydpx4JLDaoO5ujAYO658OCrzcpELwhhaPI3fX6D71YV1qQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" charset="UTF-8"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@1.12.0/build/global/luxon.min.js" integrity="sha256-o1YsUhC0RuYMR+8b0zu9vjUuJa+pnS/8rB87wcyImTM= sha384-5Wo6YmI/Cgvh/Y576jEIIhWu6IvSt5wovJxutq18DkJwbHgVBrv1PIIpUFBTxI5D sha512-9j0Zy2i7ac00T3D+W6J3bHXp5S4ak5fF84Fyejc0S5D579pdNtEvBRc3DPxd0Amv31c5UcKz9EKgZXNpPDncqw==" crossorigin="anonymous" charset="UTF-8"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">luxon.DateTime.local();</script>
 <!--  > GENERAL: BOOTSTRAP DATE(TIME)PICKER -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js" integrity="sha256-jgMYw0Xf+iO0EYC4pnX8tS4vmDqyjtJ9dwfSMMjSZuY= sha384-hzexvprs0k2Q/IHSJOfegsjdg6kTcTTVxQdgHiB4+I/915hcvse9v42LLVVM5K4e sha512-9LUemrpP5JutDNVlv4gUnNWwZXm2+vdv5hVyBs5Jv9ps7L8rfM7s3XvZpWQZ8J24NtoFObTsTyVMHb1yt3daHQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" charset="UTF-8"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js" integrity="sha256-dsMvvkha4U8Hflt7QUPXZAKLwT/BObq7M5j5AZYnmDs= sha384-2Tnqs3x0ucZkxYqJ3UX1R/fkSRkMaDsdYWsUNc0hZVikDXRHamRor+AsNJ7Pi2DA sha512-q0z6v3s4gfltHTrrMhgvsG375RfT18n+jUtUT3vOBi0PUloPA4x/NEM2zp3U0dahP4YJCfP7tAlYtOYkZv7OZw==" crossorigin="anonymous" charset="UTF-8"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-bs-daterangepicker/0.0.6/ng-bs-daterangepicker.min.js" integrity="sha256-gNo6MkJKhDMe/rKguZNSceihaZgV8qAmZq596TO0C2k= sha384-ssqNv6IP0gFZMqGCBXIchUj1hU+KtaR73qoM+4dwDrIcUFbfIsCiVHkrhF36C3yu sha512-At2HC9GDwT75iMnbAmHMeVa1FTf9vWd8jRo1iYrssIxXv7LJSfa+DPeIW9RqpQmzT+bxR2gW5cwikKMYDp0c5w==" crossorigin="anonymous" charset="UTF-8"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/datepickk@1.4.1/dist/datepickk.min.js" integrity="sha256-a3ivkpG9FQ9r9MBj0CPQRgvomhFvEo6Q3hn3c/Uqj80= sha384-RS/z/Fj3PBS/SEuZRm4W4kj0lDIHAtywamV0X74KJkilLA6fL5AqECMIkjYA0Am7 sha512-7izfFFemCc9W6mAIb6pOFEysnmTe+0hTNAMXSaxGpJw7754ugRjw7fEDUJJjCwTpY//2wDvj7rJvetBSg8AdeQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" charset="UTF-8"></script>  
 <!--  > GENERAL: CHARTS -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0/dist/Chart.min.js" integrity="sha256-Uv9BNBucvCPipKQ2NS9wYpJmi8DTOEfTA/nH2aoJALw= sha384-QzN1ywg2QLsf72ZkgRHgjkB/cfI4Dqjg6RJYQUqH6Wm8qp/MvmEYn+2NBsLnhLkr sha512-mf78KukU/a8rjr7aBRvCa2Vwg/q0tUjJhLtcK53PHEbFwCEqQ5durlzvVTgQgKpv+fyNMT6ZQT1Aq6tpNqf1mg==" crossorigin="anonymous" charset="UTF-8"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.7.5/js/mdb.min.js" integrity="sha256-RyKFOSKnuKFSYAyJlfeHdb8ljBAbLJOSh9Bz8pzhhkY= sha384-4l+KiSAWnxbgZLQwQow7VtknwS81RATqH0tAE4Yh8jjquAE9F+k81s2aZojpuox7 sha512-v3qBtRIcm5Ew3PcKHPvjBB7QFkm1XQ4WequO37YZe2IT0hRj+kdA/vtOMvb5/UrlVx1HMkV/dqA+Ka9POz6sVA==" crossorigin="anonymous" charset="UTF-8"></script> 
 
 <!--  > GENERAL: CUSTOM PROJECT SCRIPTS -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/project.js" charset="UTF-8"></script> 
    
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"> 
 // Disable automatic style injection:
 Chart.platform.disableCSSInjection = true; 
  
 console.clear();
 </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,
seems you import a library that override the bootstrap behavior.

Remove the mdb library and check again.

You mixed 2 different UI libraries.

there is the official [bootstrap theme](https://getbootstrap.com/), that is the one you use for the input & button.

And there is the [MDB](https://mdbootstrap.com/) that stand for the material design bootstrap.

You can not use both,you have to make a choice which library to use then go with it without mixing.

Hope I've helped

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <html lang="de" xml:lang="de" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" ng-app="sensorsApp">
<head>
     <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8" /> <!-- HTML5 HTTP-Header --> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> <!-- HTML4 HTTP-Header -->
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/css; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/javascript; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  
  <!-- USED CSS: GENERAL (1/2) -->
  <!--  > GENERAL: CUSTOM PROJECT STYLES -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/project.css">    
    
  <!-- USED CSS: BOOTSTRAP -->
  <!--  > BOOTSTRAP FONT LIBS: -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha256-nAmazAk6vS34Xqo0BSrTb+abbtFlgsFK7NKSi6o7Y78= sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr sha512-3M00D/rn8n+2ZVXBO9Hib0GKNpkm8MSUU/e2VNthDyBYxKWG+BftNYYcuEjXlyrSO637tidzMBXfE7sQm0INUg==" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!--  > BOOTSTRAP 4: -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha256-YLGeXaapI0/5IgZopewRJcFXomhRMlYYjugPLSyNjTY= sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T sha512-tDXPcamuZsWWd6OsKFyH6nAqh/MjZ/5Yk88T5o+aMfygqNFPan1pLyPFAndRzmOWHKT+jSDzWpJv8krj6x1LMA==" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
  <!-- USED CSS: GENERAL (2/2) -->
  <!--  > GENERAL: BOOTSTRAP DATE(TIME)PICKER -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" integrity="sha256-5Z/4A9O2iG86Ca27OwgMwLmRYt9bjLOoEpPXy7yhiSs= sha384-8wYGNo4TwC9xzqNRdt7OUN789eBPzNQlO/sxIKaJR1gkX0+Ok1kXxhHR4pZU+gP2 sha512-Dapa+NBx6nVgt1Q5L+vn8oXI+bcHD9qpWmWNlkqAIlzz6cpwb6IsEthpkmV455sUDs2FXAZKyNz4hY1Dl0xGyg==" crossorigin="anonymous">  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" integrity="sha256-7B9s/BwXySAt0TMN6/mo6NCBm8oCfFNqaeJlz/9FCpE= sha384-3J4adb6KqO9u+ZgVfdmUqKDG4qWyG2qxGdXYoCXh3YmBQURWveIDgFh22pw1E3a9 sha512-gjpWBCm7COvj1rB4CrNkBAV+Uoxivp/2LPKpZkKcnFS4dDGhQtxdNgn4b8hLltoEVHu7LktbSf8dH8Igm/vi6A==" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/datepickk@1.4.1/dist/datepickk.min.css" integrity="sha256-8pYhYq1SmTPr+/nu2genJ7ko5oPwyiY3TJN0UAAZGQw= sha384-M2Romq884NkvgBkdz3NdXBwgPBO8cCs0keFrHmCWoNQ+tJYBpktQErbvcD7gKXae sha512-zFB5O2YjVX9hdpLmz13ClhpHkX1MWNjuyfFlIiGUR9ziBrSvcpp4hx+qfpBZFsVHPHfMg1HFbC8E5uDf9Fd6HA==" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!--  > GENERAL: BOOTSTRAP CHARTS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0/dist/Chart.min.css" integrity="sha256-aa0xaJgmK/X74WM224KMQeNQC2xYKwlAt08oZqjeF0E= sha384-q9MZ/PQCC1nIFQdrr9yNOFXeSaXjv/yPOJOdBd32aODh8+EM6udfo91a6mRbEDih sha512-/zs32ZEJh+/EO2N1b0PEdoA10JkdC3zJ8L5FTiQu82LR9S/rOQNfQN7U59U9BC12swNeRAz3HSzIL2vpp4fv3w==" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <!--  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.7.5/css/mdb.min.css" integrity="sha256-VSBoWx3wZz4Z6YAMGq1toMWvJN3G1w7KH+b61PGwppA= sha384-WxBbLYERKrFMTQ9LAaSYPo5qW9PJSzV6pbbaX8PqD20S4yudCgwblvRmuhXU6iWD sha512-vltzTDeCDN3MBaISvgsAAv6vJfbJkhjTokn/UttmEVCo0UEOsm7yhgqWJ3n0d5Wz/Fl8ZZSdLyyn7YGGbGwNYg==" crossorigin="anonymous">  
   -->
  <!-- USED SCRIPTS: GENERAL (1/2) -->
  <!--  > GENERAL: Needed polyfills for working Luxon with supporting IE 10 or 11 -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.js?features=default,es5,es6,es7,String.prototype.repeat,Array.prototype.find,Array.prototype.findIndex,Math.trunc,Math.sign&flags=gated" crossorigin="anonymous" charset="UTF-8"></script>
  <!--  > GENERAL: jQuery 3 -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8= sha384-tsQFqpEReu7ZLhBV2VZlAu7zcOV+rXbYlF2cqB8txI/8aZajjp4Bqd+V6D5IgvKT sha512-+NqPlbbtM1QqiK8ZAo4Yrj2c4lNQoGv8P79DPtKzj++l5jnN39rHA/xsqn8zE9l0uSoxaCdrOgFs6yjyfbBxSg==" crossorigin="anonymous" charset="UTF-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js" integrity="sha256-jDnOKIOq2KNsQZTcBTEnsp76FnfMEttF6AV2DF2fFNE= sha384-hKAOvu4SRkR5UhOl+rvozhqPNh0VgjTz0sydNTzye3vkV6VzpbLACSgthC2bhXeV sha512-CEiA+78TpP9KAIPzqBvxUv8hy41jyI3f2uHi7DGp/Y/Ka973qgSdybNegWFciqh6GrN2UePx2KkflnQUbUhNIA==" crossorigin="anonymous" charset="UTF-8"></script>
 </head>
 <!-- define angular controller -->
 <body ng-controller="mainController">
    
    
    

    
  <div class="container justify-content-md-center justify-content-center">
   <form id="dateTimeRangeSelectionForm1" class="form-group" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-sm">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="row">
        <label class="form-control-label">Selected date/time range:</label>
       </div>
       <div class="input-group date row">
        <input type="daterange" id="dateRangePicker1" name="dateRangePicker1" class="form-control" ng-model="dateRangePicker1"></input>
        <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#dateRangePicker1">
         <button type="button" id="dateRangePicker1GlyphButton1" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" role="button"><i class="fas fa-calendar"></i></button>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>

 <!-- USED SCRIPTS: BOOTSTRAP -->
 <!--  > BOOTSTRAP GENERAL: --> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZvOgfh+ptkpoa2Y4HkRY28ir89u/+VRyDE7sB7hEEcI= sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1 sha512-5WvZa4N7Jq3TVNCp4rjcBMlc6pT3lZ7gVxjtI6IkKW+uItSa+rFgtFljvZnCxQGj8SUX5DHraKE6Mn/4smK1Cg==" crossorigin="anonymous" charset="UTF-8"></script>
 <!--  > BOOTSTRAP 4: -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha256-CjSoeELFOcH0/uxWu6mC/Vlrc1AARqbm/jiiImDGV3s= sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM sha512-Ah5hWYPzDsVHf9i2EejFBFrG2ZAPmpu4ZJtW4MfSgpZacn+M9QHDt+Hd/wL1tEkk1UgbzqepJr6KnhZjFKB+0A==" crossorigin="anonymous" charset="UTF-8"></script> 
  
 <!-- USED SCRIPTS: ANGULARJS1 -->
 <!-- AngularJS 1: -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js" integrity="sha256-23hi0Ag650tclABdGCdMNSjxvikytyQ44vYGo9HyOrU= sha384-TBbVc3SDLcWU5RloNEsoiDVvRK9iYkBNMm1OsAcOIVEASb7zzMWB0aMobj6CzKUw sha512-28WMav3WUIziq1D5l+8y2BrzN+CJgEeIyLksiKOSHWofTgaZc3RMPzvleRhXbLwnzf/C7Xnb0W6pE8PlqeRSog==" crossorigin="anonymous" charset="UTF-8"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular-route.js" integrity="sha256-AL1+LnGW9wl5bbvR2aXuGAmYsPKLYHzFbeRyHvPUHw8= sha384-I+qxwVtb8G6V2DkR4JZQBtMe7WBcZkOhEoYoYcvePXVXyQGJDRmZ5vYNRoavfaJ6 sha512-lkwD93i2YxHwDdR41e/MhAl2nm68FsG3x6MdIkmcDaNu8gTgvwyxMxHEiP11fyD9+lpgnUSnPC//NwhAYPS58g==" crossorigin="anonymous" charset="UTF-8"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular-sanitize.js" integrity="sha256-fe1CNxJdqcp2+X9H3Sd0yqtxOv0cyK9DN52g+NhnBgQ= sha384-I3+wmR2cuftFax1/khkYCw2l/24RBOm7dRvcOCGUesC9HveXuL9Gt2QI82rmENt6 sha512-Qxi9FQdJbTxZaVDSVzShM6J67oXjN6MEZ8nn5Fl83fdd9dxsZqX6yDJspSjeKK6Q12FOx6DIQd8l/fe9h1r0ng==" crossorigin="anonymous" charset="UTF-8"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-translate/2.18.1/angular-translate.min.js" integrity="sha256-aOs2ICGLk6gC0UX7UDhvXn/gvsa2qx5bUipyQFKmoOs= sha384-A+zN6Osqnkp8ThR1gJEJ4/dVw2Zwfz0llOo7BnyciCz1isb6OENEo8xfHx1gTWLX sha512-U5WInQAQvpR1C+dLWjcpVygbeof6FylSTlLbUC6eQml4iiEKcNhtPi0GSLCNRIcycohEV5IjfU/HPNHx+lI+Dw==" crossorigin="anonymous" charset="UTF-8"></script>  
  
 <!-- USED SCRIPTS: GENERAL (2/2) -->
 <!--  > GENERAL: ANGULARJS CONTROLLER -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/controller.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
 <!--  > GENERAL: MOMENT.JS -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js" integrity="sha256-AdQN98MVZs44Eq2yTwtoKufhnU+uZ7v2kXnD5vqzZVo= sha384-5wvDEKtdpg/AAUpUHtcjYKVs1qv2V/UFPCN2FNvgePyaKmpBjW+LrboDEuS5ssBe sha512-hlLgIh4nncb2yc4YPtWk5wOykcFxF0fBd5rHfJ6xsALI2khY3H8LbivswJE5Fpz7hws7CJCqOzdyjWHiKJYl+A==" crossorigin="anonymous" charset="UTF-8"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js" integrity="sha256-15jnh2lee6Li94j6XCbw8PRzNZe29O/W9i97yXVyRmA= sha384-bnidgWGLxxEZXPx1eX9mXLAvpkXkRL3iQbkgEksVnj5tlsiymxadIxiM7q5a88Ji sha512-27vEz6bCFnYQ6tNjguaA5DK5TOGme/fdDxbEtuZxydpx4JLDaoO5ujAYO658OCrzcpELwhhaPI3fX6D71YV1qQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" charset="UTF-8"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@1.12.0/build/global/luxon.min.js" integrity="sha256-o1YsUhC0RuYMR+8b0zu9vjUuJa+pnS/8rB87wcyImTM= sha384-5Wo6YmI/Cgvh/Y576jEIIhWu6IvSt5wovJxutq18DkJwbHgVBrv1PIIpUFBTxI5D sha512-9j0Zy2i7ac00T3D+W6J3bHXp5S4ak5fF84Fyejc0S5D579pdNtEvBRc3DPxd0Amv31c5UcKz9EKgZXNpPDncqw==" crossorigin="anonymous" charset="UTF-8"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">luxon.DateTime.local();</script>
 <!--  > GENERAL: BOOTSTRAP DATE(TIME)PICKER -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js" integrity="sha256-jgMYw0Xf+iO0EYC4pnX8tS4vmDqyjtJ9dwfSMMjSZuY= sha384-hzexvprs0k2Q/IHSJOfegsjdg6kTcTTVxQdgHiB4+I/915hcvse9v42LLVVM5K4e sha512-9LUemrpP5JutDNVlv4gUnNWwZXm2+vdv5hVyBs5Jv9ps7L8rfM7s3XvZpWQZ8J24NtoFObTsTyVMHb1yt3daHQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" charset="UTF-8"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js" integrity="sha256-dsMvvkha4U8Hflt7QUPXZAKLwT/BObq7M5j5AZYnmDs= sha384-2Tnqs3x0ucZkxYqJ3UX1R/fkSRkMaDsdYWsUNc0hZVikDXRHamRor+AsNJ7Pi2DA sha512-q0z6v3s4gfltHTrrMhgvsG375RfT18n+jUtUT3vOBi0PUloPA4x/NEM2zp3U0dahP4YJCfP7tAlYtOYkZv7OZw==" crossorigin="anonymous" charset="UTF-8"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-bs-daterangepicker/0.0.6/ng-bs-daterangepicker.min.js" integrity="sha256-gNo6MkJKhDMe/rKguZNSceihaZgV8qAmZq596TO0C2k= sha384-ssqNv6IP0gFZMqGCBXIchUj1hU+KtaR73qoM+4dwDrIcUFbfIsCiVHkrhF36C3yu sha512-At2HC9GDwT75iMnbAmHMeVa1FTf9vWd8jRo1iYrssIxXv7LJSfa+DPeIW9RqpQmzT+bxR2gW5cwikKMYDp0c5w==" crossorigin="anonymous" charset="UTF-8"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/datepickk@1.4.1/dist/datepickk.min.js" integrity="sha256-a3ivkpG9FQ9r9MBj0CPQRgvomhFvEo6Q3hn3c/Uqj80= sha384-RS/z/Fj3PBS/SEuZRm4W4kj0lDIHAtywamV0X74KJkilLA6fL5AqECMIkjYA0Am7 sha512-7izfFFemCc9W6mAIb6pOFEysnmTe+0hTNAMXSaxGpJw7754ugRjw7fEDUJJjCwTpY//2wDvj7rJvetBSg8AdeQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" charset="UTF-8"></script>  
 <!--  > GENERAL: CHARTS -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0/dist/Chart.min.js" integrity="sha256-Uv9BNBucvCPipKQ2NS9wYpJmi8DTOEfTA/nH2aoJALw= sha384-QzN1ywg2QLsf72ZkgRHgjkB/cfI4Dqjg6RJYQUqH6Wm8qp/MvmEYn+2NBsLnhLkr sha512-mf78KukU/a8rjr7aBRvCa2Vwg/q0tUjJhLtcK53PHEbFwCEqQ5durlzvVTgQgKpv+fyNMT6ZQT1Aq6tpNqf1mg==" crossorigin="anonymous" charset="UTF-8"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.7.5/js/mdb.min.js" integrity="sha256-RyKFOSKnuKFSYAyJlfeHdb8ljBAbLJOSh9Bz8pzhhkY= sha384-4l+KiSAWnxbgZLQwQow7VtknwS81RATqH0tAE4Yh8jjquAE9F+k81s2aZojpuox7 sha512-v3qBtRIcm5Ew3PcKHPvjBB7QFkm1XQ4WequO37YZe2IT0hRj+kdA/vtOMvb5/UrlVx1HMkV/dqA+Ka9POz6sVA==" crossorigin="anonymous" charset="UTF-8"></script> 
 
 <!--  > GENERAL: CUSTOM PROJECT SCRIPTS -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/project.js" charset="UTF-8"></script> 
    
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"> 
 // Disable automatic style injection:
 Chart.platform.disableCSSInjection = true; 
  
 console.clear();
 </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is crazy. Yes, that's it reg. the visualization bug. But without btn class, all button hover effects are removed. I used the btn class according to this official bootstrap documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/ . Last week, the desired visualization works fine also with given btn class. Today, it's corrupt. Now, I removed the btn class for a good visualization. But this doesn't explain why it worked until last week and not today (no changes). Thank for your help. :)

Comment: I have updated my answer. seems ok now. and I found your error.

You imported another css library that override the bootstrap "btn" class.

Comment: Yes, that's the solution. I don't understand why is working fine until the last week (also with given issue-triggered CSS-lib and given btn class at all buttons), but it's ok for me and all issues are fixed. Thank's a lot. :) (y)

Comment: Maybe it was working fine because you recently add it.

Comment: Or maybe it was loaded first (if you import the mdb library before the bootstrap one it won't override it), so maybe import used to be before